# Excel randarray - create random number, duplicate number has same random number, no other duplication

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

In excel, I need to create random numbers that repeat when the number is in the list more than once.

So, 1 on the list would have the same random number, but this number would not repeat anywhere else on the list.

Sample date

[image]

How it should look

[image]

Thanks for your help

I have a data set of over 75,000 records some repeat up to 8 times and some are only on the list once.

How it should look

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
=LET(list,DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),randoms,TAKE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(99999),RANDARRAY(99999)),ROWS(list)),XLOOKUP(list,list,randoms))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, I came to somewhat of the same answer with `=INDEX(SORTBY(ROW(1:99999),RANDARRAY(99999)),DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1))`

Comment: That's a good idea, assuming OP's customer numbers are sensible.